# How to remove traps from base?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I accidentally added some traps in my war base. How can I remove the traps?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to remove traps - they can only help you. For the regular game, you don't have to re-arm them, so there's no expense if you don't want to pay it, and for the war base, you always want traps.

If for some reason you want to make it easier for the opposing clan, you can move the trap to the edge where it is unlikely to be triggered.